# How can I create code for print slower in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created these functions, but they do not work, even with the sayNoLine function defined like the following:

```
def sayNoLine (x):
     print (x, end = '')

def sayNoLine (x):
     sys.stdout.write (x)

def printSlowly (* args, Thetime = 0.5):
     tt = getTime ()
     txt = ''
     for i in ranlen (args):
         txt + = str (args [i])
     print ('first time: {0}'. format (tt-getTime ()))
     for time in ranlen (txt):
         sayNoLigne (txt [time])
         att (thetime)
     print ()
     print ('second time: {0}'. format (getTime () - tt))
```

each time the code was waiting for the print () function (so with a line break) before displaying the text it is:

```
print ( 't' end = '')
# output:
print ( 'e', end = '')
# output:
print ( 's' end = '')
# output:
print ( 't' end = '')
# output:
print ()
# output: test
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces between almost everything? This is more difficult to read than you might expect.

Comment: Per PEP-8, `print('e', end='')` would be an example of the preferred spacing.

Comment: By the way, the code sample you provided won't run as-is due to things like `sayNoLigne` vs `sayNoLine`, `+ =`, and some missing functions like `att`, `getTime`, and `ranlen`. Please make sure to provide a [MCVE] in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Python 3.3 you can add `flush=True` to your print calls. For example:

```
print('e', end='', flush=True)
```